# Grub Enable Swap

Tags: ubuntu, grub, docker

No matter what i try i just cant enable swap, docker info always show.

WARNING: No swap limit support

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 this is my grub line.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modset=0 swapaccount=1"

I've followed the instructions to the letter about enabling swap but nothing. https://pterodactyl.io/wings/1.0/installing.html#configure-daemon

I've also tried

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cdgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"

that didnt work ether.

Comment: I've googled the error message, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342735/53467) on our sister site came up.

Comment: If you have any information to add, edit your question, instead of submitting a comment